# countdowntimer in OnlineExam autosubmit with time elapsed & load next data by AJAX & if page refresh then next load with old time when refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used Reverse countdown to zero from time set to minutes

A student need to appear exam and complete it for a given time in minutes.

1>After n minutes the page must be auto submitted.

i>if yes,then the page must be submitted.But during that duration the countdown must continued.

ii>if exit,then student must proceed the exam for rest of his time duration.

```
$('#hour_timer').countdowntimer({
    hours: hours,
    minutes: minutes,
    seconds: seconds,
    size: "xs",
    tickInterval: 1,
    timeUp: timeisUp
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $('#hour_timer').countdowntimer({
hours: hours,
minutes: minutes,
seconds: seconds,
size: "xs",
tickInterval: 1,
timeUp: timeisUp
});
```

Here 
      **timeisUp** is function which invoke after times up. Which fulfill my requirement of times up issue.

And save time after each question submission which helps me to next time to load the question with remaining time with little bit calculation.